# How do I link my products such that it belong to a specific customer - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL database, I would like to enquire how do I link multiple products that were submitted by the customer such that I know these products belong to this customer.

Currently in my PHP, when customer submitted their order, I would save their information and products into the database. And I would link the customer_info and payment_info table via:

```
UPDATE customer_payment_information 
SET customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY customer_id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

This way both the customer_id(see image) would have the same value.

Now how do I write the query such that if customer-submitted two or more products and those products has the customer_id?

checkout cart table:
[checkout cart table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJeWw.png) &
[checkout cart table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n5uT.png)

customer info table:
[customer info table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ctm.png) &
[customer info table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F21FO.png)

payment info table:
[payment info table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdDLo.png) &
[payment info table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY87M.png)

NEW TABLE RELATION:[NEW TABLE RELATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHX5w.png)

Comment: some of my datatype is longtext is because of encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Review your database and application design**

The way you link `Customer` info with `Payment` info is wrong. It partially works in this specific case because  you just create the customer, so the last id inserted in the customer table "must be" linked to the payment.
But it's a hack, and I strongly advise you to avoid these types of asumptions, it can break in so many different ways. It only works if when you register a payment, your customer is a new one (else, he will already be in the database at another id, and the payment will be linked to the wrong customer).

What you need is a way to retrieve the good customer id before linking in the payment table. The problem is your tables are not really well designed to handle your case. I don't know much about PHP but this is how it can be done when a user submit one or many products

1. Create tables for each entity :

   - `Customer` (id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, ...)
   - `Customer_Payment` (id, credit_card_number, ccv, expiration_date, ..., customer_id)
   - `Product` (id, name, price, ...)
   - `Order` (id, customer_payment_id, product_id, quantity)

In `Custom_Payment` table, custom_id will be a foreign key referencing the Customer table. This way, a customer can have multiple credit cards registered.
An `Order` will be a `Product` linked to a `Customer Payment` with a given quantity.

2. Apply the right logic in your website

   - When a new customer register on your website : fill in the `Customer` table with an insert sql query. He could also fill in one or many payments methods. Each payment added will be a new insert on the `Customer_Payment` table.
   - Same logic for the product, each product on your website should be a row in the Product table
   - When a logged in customer arrived on a product page and click on the "Buy" button with a given quantity, a new row should be inserted on the Order table (referencing both the product and the customer payment info)

This is a (simple) example and just an idea of implementation. You need to adapt it to your needs, but the main idea is that you should really think of your database and application design, otherwise you will be rapidly locked in strange case where your design won't let you make a working software.

Comment: Sorry, my website doesn't have a register/login feature, it is  website that allow customer to buy product on without the need of registering an account. So all user information, credit card info are new, thats why I wrote that sql in my question

Comment: Ok but even without registration, I don't think it's a good thing to do all the logic in the SQL statements. You need to add logic in your backend (PHP) to retrieve customer_payme_id info. This way you won't have to "guess" the customer_payment id with a hack, you will just have to link it to the product

Comment: Hi could I confirm my new table relation whether if I am on the right track. I have uploaded the image on my question.

Comment: Customer payment and Customer seem OK to me. But your Customer Order table is not, because you duplicates the name and credit card info. And the product info should be on a separate Product table. You really need to split the product from the order. This is the only way to avoid duplication. A product exists on its own, so it should have its own table, exactly like a customer exists on his own. An Order is a Product with a quantity for a Customer Payment, your Order table should shows exactly that

Comment: my product info is on a separate product table, is the catering_menu table.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that. So you just have to remove email, creditCardInformation, productName from Customer_Order. You should also remove the totalPrice from Customer_Order as it is a "calculated field". You can retrieve this information by doing product.price * customer_order.quantity

Comment: sorry I have updated my table again. Is the relationship correct? I'm using one to many relationships for the tables

Comment: For me it's all good. I think you just forget to remove the customer_id from the customer_payment_information table, you already have the foreign key as your last attribute (customer_information_customer_id)

Comment: Yes I just noticed it as well. Thank alot of the explanation. One more thing just to confirm my understanding. When the customer click on checkout, presonal info will be stored at (customer_information) table, credit card info will be stored at (customer_payment_information) table, product customer has chosen stored at (catering_menu) table ?

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it will help you with your problem, don't hesitate to tell if you succeed doing what you want with your new database design

Comment: so by simply calling my customer_order table, I would be able to see all the information ?

Comment: yes, if the right logic is implemented in your PHP website. The way you modify your database will not magically resolve everything, it's the first step to work with a properly design database. This way it should be easier to insert, retrieve, modify and delete data. If your PHP logic make the rights calls to insert data in the customer_order table, it should be quite easy to retrieve the info

Answer (score 0):

the idea is right ,
you should have table named `users` ,all of userdata is stored in this table (firstname , lastname , phonenumber , ....) . 
the important thing is the unique `id` .

after this , when you add `products` table , you should have `id ,userid ,title ,price , ....` .

so when the user creates new product , you will take the `id` of user and store it in products `userid` , then you just easily get all products that user have .

```
function Get_Products($userid)
{
    $allProducts = [];
    $products = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE userid=$userid");
    while ($product = $products->fetch_assoc()) {
        $allProducts[] = $product;
    }
    return $allProducts;
}
```

now you can get all the products that user have !

Comment: Do I store literally every information of the user in one big table or split into two ? Cause currently, I have two table for user, 1) Credit card info  2) Personal info.
When you say products table, do you mean the check out cart table that store user product ? or the product table that has the product info ?

Comment: the users table is for the personal info . if you want to store the card data , it's recommended to create new table as you did .